# Why is the supported operator not supported?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Why does Powershell say that a supported operator is not supported?

I have the following (simplified) code containing a [case-sensitive not-equal operator](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html):

```
$filter_accountchanged = { (sAMAccountName -eq $username) -and (GivenName -cne $givenname) }
try {
        if (Get-ADUser -filter $filter_accountchanged) { # update aduser }
catch {
        Write-host $_.Exception
```

In what situations can this result in the following error that I am seeing?

> Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException: Error parsing query: ' (sAMAccountName -eq $username) -and ((GivenName -cne $givenname))' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: -cne' at position: '50'.
>      at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.QueryParser.yyparse()
>      at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.QueryParser..ctor(String query, VariableExpressionConverter varExpressionConverter, ConvertSearchFilterDelegate searchFilterConverterDelegate)
>      at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADGetCmdletBase`3.BeginProcessingOverride()

The query succeeds when I remove the `c` from `cne`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not all operators are supported by Powershell's filter param. Your filter will/does work with a | Where() statement (it did on my local system).

[Powershell filter support list from 2011](http://blogs.metcorpconsulting.com/tech/?p=76) (which lists "ne" as an option)

Comment: Let's hope that will be resolved in a future version, it's not very consistent.

For future reference, the following code works http://pastebin.com/vDcJEvXu

Comment: I haven't looked at Powershell 3, yet, but hoping that all operators become available. Good idea to only WHERE on the givenname. Should keep your code from being much slower.

Comment: Could you please give code in your answer. `| Where ()` is also not working because Get-ADuser requires you to have a filter by default

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the `Get-ADUser` Filter parameter, not PowerShell's in particular. Try -ne instead.